# Check if class member is a class object

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class whose member is another class object among other members. I would like to know how to determine whether the this field is a java class (user defined). 
That is, I have something like this: 
The user passes the name of a java class. If the package contains a class by this name, then I get all the declared fields of this class and do a DFS kind of operation on those data members that are class objects.

```
class A {
  private String c;
  private B b;
}

class B {
  private int d;
  private String f;
}
```

So now in A, I only have to select B and visit B's members. 
How to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there criteria for distinguishing classes you're interested in from classes you want to ignore? Package name, for instance?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but something sounds... fishy. Perhaps you should explain the big-picture goal, and you may find there's a much better solution than dealing with the packages and such...

Comment: ok. So I found doing this works.     if(allDeclaredFields[i].getType().getPackage() == null && !allDeclaredFields[i].getType().isPrimitive()) {
Class thisClass = allDeclaredFields[i].getClass();
}

Comment: I found that selects B in A since package of String is java.lang and for primitive types (which I dont want to select) i do !isPrimitive()

Comment: What about Strings?  They aren't primitives, but you want to skip them too, don't you, together with all standard Java library types?

Comment: So basically I want to visit all user defined classes inside a class and ignore the value types.

Comment: yes. This skips Strings. But doesnt skip arrays of primitive types. Or for that matter even array of Integer like wrapper types.

Comment: so this seems to do it: (atleast for now): if(allDeclaredFields[i].getType().getPackage() == null 
&& !allDeclaredFields[i].getType().isPrimitive() && !allDeclaredFields[i].getType().isArray()) {
String className = allDeclaredFields[i].getType().getName(); }

Answer (score 1):

There is one more trick. But results strictly depends on a classloader. It may help you checking if a class is custom user class. Try running this code to determine location of jar:

```
    ProtectionDomain domain = allDeclaredFields[i].getClass().getProtectionDomain();
    System.out.println("domain: " + domain);
    CodeSource codeSource = domain.getCodeSource();
    if(codeSource != null) {
       System.out.println("location: " + codeSource.getLocation());
    } else {
        System.out.println("null location, probably JRE class");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for letting me know this one. But doesnt seem to work :( It says JRE class for class objects also.

Comment: for class objects such as java.lang.String or ArrayList it will say so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Java reflection. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html for more information (click on members, should be what you need)

Comment: I am using reflection only. But I find there is no way to do this atleast directly.

Comment: btw, if you just want to load the members of user defined classes, perhaps you should just use a custom class loader. If there are exceptions, then the class doesnt exist. Elsewise, perhaps just show them the members then?

Comment: sorry. i havent used class loader before. So did not reply. Let me look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your qusestion correctly you are trying to find whether a object belongs to a class or not.There is a java operator called instanceof to check it

```
if(b instanceof B){
//b is an object of B
}
```

Comment: It seems that this is NOT the OP's question.  He wants to know how to tell whether something is a user-defined class (as opposed to say, a primitive)

Comment: yes. I do not know beforehand that b will be an instance of B